# How to prove oracle machine solves "Halting prblm

Tags: computation-theory

I need some help with showing Halting problem can be solved by an oracle machine. I don't know how to start to proving.

Comment: Probably rather a question for [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an oracle is assumed to correctly solve some specific problem; we can imagine oracles for any problem, even undecidable ones.

The answer to your question is simple. An oracle can solve the halting problem because an oracle, defined by you, can be assumed to solve anything. That is the point of oracles.

Possibly, your problem is that you are given an oracle for some other specific problem and you are asked to show that the oracle for that problem can be used to solve instances of the halting problem. This is an entirely other task and it may happen that this other oracle does or doesn't allow you to solve instances of the halting problem. In any event, you would need to show that it does or doesn't; it wouldn't be immediately obvious in general.

Answer (score -1):

The halting problem is **the problem of determining whether some program will *finish running* or *continue to run* forever**. This, given some *input* and some *description* of the program. Note that the halting problem is undecidable over Turing machines and it is one of the first examples of a decision problem.*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem (accessed Jan 21, 2018).*

An example that illustrates the halting problem would be a while loop that never meets/does not have an exit condition. This program *continues to run forever*. Consider the other end of the spectrum, where a program consisting of one java System.out.println("HELLO") statement would print the contents between the quotes to console and then it will *halt*.

An **Oracle machine** is used to *study decision problems* and it has an **input**, **black box**, and **output*. Inside the black box we have our Turing machine. The oracle... or Turing machine with black box... solves certain decision problems in a single operation. Undecidable problems, or problems which are not computable can be used. *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine (Accessed Jan 21, 2018).*

The halting problem is an *undecidable problem*. So we can use an Oracle machine to understand it. Now go search Google Scholar for some info on Oracle machines, and solving the halting problem. Good luck.